# Symfony 4 entities in sub folders

Tags: symfony4

Just a quick question. I can put my controllers in sub folders by using namespace App\Controller\FolderName;

Works fine, but can this also be done with entities? When there are a lot of them it becomes messy and would be nice to organis them into folders, such as all the user entities in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

go to config/packages/doctrine.yaml to orm area:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App\Subfolder1:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Subfolder1/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Subfolder1\Entity'
            alias: AppSubfolder1
        App\Subfolder2:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Subfolder2/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Subfolder2\Entity'
            alias: AppSubfolder2
        App\Subfolder3:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Subfolder3/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Subfolder3\Entity'
            alias: AppSubfolder3
```